# Metadata navigation on all pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have added metadata navigation as explained from the below site,
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-A8DDFCD1-A486-4E0F-B1B1-F10CA79FA9BC

The matadata navigation only appears on the pages library . i was just wondering if there is any way we can add them through out the site.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata navigation can only be configured and used in the list and library.

After enabling the metadata navigation and configuring the metadata navigation settings for a list/library, it will work only in this list/library.